# Does every published Rails Event Store event have a timestamp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, timestamp, metadata, rails-event-store

Does every [Rails Event Store](http://railseventstore.org) event that's been published automatically get assigned a `timestamp`? I'm trying to build functionality that relies upon a timestamp automatically being present for events `deserialize`d from the `event_store` within a job, but I don't know that I can rely on that. I'm hoping that one does not need to manually add a `timestamp` to the event's `metadata` in order for a `timestamp` to be present, since it doesn't appear that that's been done anywhere in the code base I'm working on. I'm aware that [the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby_event_store/RubyEventStore%2FEvent:timestamp) indicate that the return value of the `RubyEventStore::Event#timestamp` method can be `nil`, but I'm hoping that it won't be `nil` for published events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you provide your own timestamp (the `:timestamp` key in metadata) each stored event will have metadata enriched with current time - see https://github.com/RailsEventStore/rails_event_store/blob/master/ruby_event_store/lib/ruby_event_store/client.rb#L311

It can be `nil`. But only if your `clock` provided to RailsEventStore client will return nil.

In upcoming Rails Event Store 2.0 release we will also add the validity time (`valid_at` attribute in metadata) that will allow to implement BI Temporal event sourcing. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you! How could I know whether there's a `clock` being provided to the RES client that will return `nil`?

Comment: By default the clock is defined here: https://github.com/RailsEventStore/rails_event_store/blob/master/ruby_event_store/lib/ruby_event_store/client.rb#L327

Unless you pass something different there is no way that timestamp could be nil.